# Android Get list of files in a http (web) folder

Tags: android

In Android, is there a way to get a list of the zip files on a web server which allows file browsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you just have to load the URL into a WebView instance. See the Basic usage chapter: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Can you (or someone else) explain this in more detail?

Comment: @Snailer He just wanted to know how if there is a built in solution for displaying websites. Webview is the proper way to do that.

Comment: It seems like he wanted a list (perhaps a string array) of files in a certain directory. The fact that he accepted this answer must mean he found another way to do so, like a PHP script that prints out files then getting js to dump the HTML.

Comment: @Snaller If you mean you would like to fetch the files and store it locally, you would need to connect to this server with UrlConnection or HttpUrlConnection and somehow fetch the files. Since the OP didn't exactly specify what he wants, I guessed he only wanted to display the list of zip files.